# Flutter connectivity_plus Package Builds in VS Code but Fails in Xcode

Tags: flutter, xcode

I'm encountering an issue with my Flutter project that utilizes the connectivity_plus package. When I build and run the project from Visual Studio Code, everything works perfectly fine on both an iOS simulator and a physical device. However, when I attempt to build the same project directly from Xcode, the build fails with no explicit error related to connectivity_plus.

What I've Tried:

```
Running flutter pub get and ensuring all dependencies are up to date.
Checking that connectivity_plus is correctly added to my pubspec.yaml.
Cleaning the build folder in Xcode (Shift + Command + K) and removing derived data.
Ensuring that my Podfile is correctly set up and running pod install in the ios directory.
Running flutter clean followed by flutter build ios before opening the .xcworkspace file in Xcode.
```

Despite these efforts, the project builds successfully in VS Code but not when I try to build it directly in Xcode. The error messages in Xcode are not pointing to any specific issues with connectivity_plus. This leads to a peculiar situation where the app runs fine when initiated from VS Code but fails to build in Xcode.

Question:

Has anyone faced a similar issue, or does anyone have insights into what might be causing this discrepancy between building in VS Code and Xcode? Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot or fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Environment Details:

```
Flutter version: 3.19.1
connectivity_plus version: 5.0.2
Xcode version: 15
```

Thank you in advance for your help and suggestions!

Running flutter pub get and ensuring all dependencies are up to date.
Checking that connectivity_plus is correctly added to my pubspec.yaml.
Cleaning the build folder in Xcode (Shift + Command + K) and removing derived data.
Ensuring that my Podfile is correctly set up and running pod install in the ios directory.
Running flutter clean followed by flutter build ios before opening the .xcworkspace file in Xcode.

Comment: Faced same issue